# What is the co-domain of the probability density function of a continuous random variable?

Tags: probability, continuity

The text I'm referring to states it to be [0, infinity), but I don't understand why it shouldn't be [0,1] as it is in the case of Discrete random variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the area under a curve can be one even if the curve goes above one.  Think about $f(x)=2x$ for $0\leq x\leq 1$.  The area is one even though the curve goes up to two.

Meanwhile for a discrete distribution each bar represents the probability of a single event, so each bar cannot be higher than one.  For a continuous, in contrast, the probability of each individual event is zero, only ranges of values have positive probability.